# using WSDL.exe to convert a web service to a .cs class

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, wsdl

I have downloaded the "ShipWebReference" from ups.com and it is working great when used in visual studio as a "web reference"
what i am trying to do is convert this set of wsdl file and wsd files to a .CS class
I have successfully done above with another UPS web reference: "XAVWSWebReference" however no luck with "ShipWebReference"

i am using the VS2015 command prompt as administrator and running the command "wsdl"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsdl /language:C# "C:\Users\Mark Kordahi\Desktop\ShipSample\ShipWSSample\Web References\ShipWebReference\Ship.wsdl"

I am expecting a new file generated successfully message however above code is failing with below error:

> Microsoft (R) Web Services Description Language Utility [Microsoft (R)
>   .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0] Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved. Error: Unable to import binding
>   'ShipBinding' from namespace
>   'http://www.ups.com/WSDL/XOLTWS/Ship/v1.0'.
>     - Unable to import operation 'ProcessShipment'.
>     - The element 'http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0:UPSSecurity' is
>   missing.

If you would like more help, please type "wsdl /?".

I have uploaded a copy of the wsdl package under this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-XPKV1xHBoifaXvqxjhXbEZzAWuPvOKO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you sure it's still maintained? I keep getting a lot of 'not found' errors when I try to look up info on their site about their wsdl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not including other files/classes when running this wsdl.
apparently ship.wsdl requires other wsdl such as UPSSecurity.wsdl

Answer (score 0):

i think you got this error because of this:

`'http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0:UPSSecurity'`

The ups.com page you requested cannot be found